# search in solrj by particular id

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a list of Id's and I want to search a document based on those Id and the format of Id is like this -

```
id:<382-84623-87309-184579-JHSAG@gmail.com>2016-04-22T21:12:30Z
```

I wrote a code-

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("id:<382-84623-87309-184579-JHSAG@gmail.com>2016-04-22T21:12:30Z");
query.setFields("id","from","subject");

QueryResponse response = server.query(query);  // server is a CloudSolrServer object

SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();

for(i=0;i<results.size();i++) {
    system.out.println(results.get(i);
}
```

But I am getting error

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'name:': Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    <BAREOPER> ...
    "(" ...
    "*" ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <TERM> ...
    <PREFIXTERM> ...
    <WILDTERM> ...
    <REGEXPTERM> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    <LPARAMS> ...
    <NUMBER> ...
```

I tried to add the escape character in Id value in this line

```
query.setQuery("id:<382-84623-87309-184579-JHSAG@gmail.com>2016-04-22T21:12:30Z");
```

but it doesn't find any document.. Can somebody please help me to write above line using escape character Or suggest some other way to achieve it.

FYI, I found 1 link on stackoverflow but that doesn't help me, I don't have that link now to paste it here.

**Solr Version**: 4.10.3

Comment: are you able to query the same through solr admin ui...? did you get the result there ..? whats the field type used..? can you share the schema.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how to define field id  in your solr's schema ?

if your id is string field , then use double quote surround your search keyword , 
if your id is text field , then use lucene's escape in your keyword

```
QueryParser.escape("")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assign id value to variable and use that variable. solr will tokenize your query so you should consider using Phrase query here. like

`docID="\"<382-84623-87309-184579-JHSAG@gmail.com>2016-04-22T21:12:30Z\""`

```
query.setQuery("id:"+docID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the clearest solution:

```
query.setQuery("id:"+QueryParser.escape("<382-84623-87309-184579-JHSAG@gmail.com>2016-04-22T21:12:30Z");
```